# Codeigniter 2: How to switch auto-loaded lang file to different language

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

From CodeIgniter User Guide

> If you find that you need a particular language globally throughout
>   your application, you can tell CodeIgniter to auto-load it during
>   system initialization. This is done by opening the
>   application/config/autoload.php file and adding the language(s) to the
>   autoload array.

I store information about user language in the session.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('lang', $lang);
```

How to change language (to the language used by the user) of autoloaded global lang file  (The default language is loaded from config.php - which is obviously understood)

```
$autoload['language'] = array('global');
```

Is this possible, and if not, how it should be done ?
Do I need to extends CI_Controller?

Answer (score 3):

after all, I think the best solution is to extend CI_controller
Simple like that

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // Global Lang File
        $this->lang->load('global', $this->session->userdata('lang'));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but you will need to load the language you need from the session using :

```
$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');
```

From the manual :

Where filename is the name of the file you wish to load (without the file extension), and language is the language set containing it (ie, english). If the second parameter is missing, the default language set in your application/config/config.php file will be used.

Once your desired language file is loaded you can access any line of text using this function:

```
$this->lang->line('language_key');
```

Of course your languages files would be in "application/language"